# Setting Up Scopes with a HABTM Relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between Categories and Posts. I'm setting up a scope to query all Posts in a specific category. The scope below works, but it seems fairly verbose. Is there a better way this could be refactored?

In the Post model:

```
scope :in_category, ->(category) { joins(:categories).where(categories_posts: {category_id: category.id} ) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any other way to this in `Post` model.

But create this scope is unnecessary. Assuming that you already has a `Category` instance, this works:

```
category.posts
```

**Edit:**

If you're looking for a method to call on the `Post` class, use this scope (but I think this is reinvent the wheel, since the Rails already provide the method above):

```
class Post
  scope :in_category ->(category) { category.posts }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am aware that the collection can be called on the other class.  In this case I was looking specifically for a method to call on the Post class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a scope, you can use a class method:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.in_category(category)
    category.posts
  end
end
```

`Post.in_category(Category.first)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.in_category(category_id)
    category_id.blank? ? all : joins(:category_id).where(:categories_posts => {category_id: category_id})
end
```

This approach has some benefits

- You can call Post.in_category(id) and get specific posts in that
  category as you asked.
- Post.in_category(nil) will return all posts, this is helpful if you want to concatenate this scope with other scopes.
- Post.in_category([id1, id2]) will return posts in both categories, id 1 and id2 (in this case it might be nice to rename the scope as in_categories)